# File export not working in Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to export a file upon button click event. The structure of my app is like this.

UpdatePanel
   TabContainer
    Tab1
      UserControl (Button is in UserControl)
    Tab1
   TabContainer

I tried setting PostbackTrigger but it says control not found exception.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Page Load try using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterPostbackControl(YourControl);
```

Comment: The problem is that the Script Manager is in MasterPage while the button is in the user control

Comment: do var ScriptManager = page.master.findcontrol("scriptManagersID"); then ScriptManager.RegisterPostbackControl(YourControl);